# read/input hexadecimal number from keyboard

Tags: regex, perl

How to read/input hexadecimal numbers from keyboard in Perl?

For example I have a hex number '3e' and want to read this from a keyboard into a variable. The variable should store the decimal equivalent (62) of '3e'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$hex_value = <STDIN>;
$decimal_value = hex $hex_value;
```

Explanation:

1. To read in data from standard input, use `<STDIN>`;
2. To convert a hex value to decimal value, use `hex`;

Answer (score 1):

Read the input into a scalar as you normally would, say, `$foo`, and do this:

```
$bar = hex($foo)
```